# Extract data in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to make query to get the rows of the table by extracting data from it?

This is my table:

```
leave_count_id  leave_count     leave_user_id   leave_id        leave_earned
1               0.0             1               1               15.000
2               0.0             1               2               15.000
3               2.5             2               1               15.000
4               0.0             2               2               15.000
5               2.0             3               1               15.000
6               1.0             3               2               15.000
7               2.0             4               1               15.000
8               1.0             4               2               15.000
```

And this is what I want to get:

```
leave_user_id   sickLeave   vacationLeave
1               0           0
2               0           2.5
3               1           2
4               1           2
```

My sql code is this:

```
SELECT leave_user_id, slCount, vlCount

FROM (
SELECT
(SELECT leave_count FROM tbl_leave_count lc WHERE leave_id = 1 and lc.leave_user_id = leave_user_id) as vlCount,
(SELECT leave_count FROM tbl_leave_count lc WHERE leave_id = 2 and lc.leave_user_id = leave_user_id) as slCount,
FROM
tbl_leave_count

WHERE lc.leave_user_id = leave_user_id
) T
```

But it has error. I dont know what to do. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why don't you use Group By ? bdw the error is You need * after 2nd Select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each user has one entry for sick leave, and one entry for vacation, and no other entries, then the following simple pivot query should work:

```
SELECT leave_user_id,
      MAX(CASE WHEN leave_id = 2 THEN leave_count END) AS sickLeave,
      MAX(CASE WHEN leave_id = 1 THEN leave_count END) AS vacationLeave
FROM tbl_leave_count
GROUP BY leave_user_id
```

A pivot query uses a trick when grouping records.  When computing sick leave in the case of the above query, for each `leave_user_id` group of records, it takes the maximum of the `leave_count` column.  There are only two records, and hence two values.  One value is the number we want in the result set, and the other one is `NULL`.  The `MAX()` function ignores nulls, so we are left with just the data we actually want.

If users can have multiple records for sick and vacation leave, then you can try this instead:

```
SELECT leave_user_id,
      SUM(CASE WHEN leave_id = 2 THEN leave_count ELSE 0 END) AS sickLeave,
      SUM(CASE WHEN leave_id = 1 THEN leave_count ELSE 0 END) AS vacationLeave
FROM tbl_leave_count
GROUP BY leave_user_id
```

Comment: Nice! It takes me so many hours to do this. Your code works. Thank you very much. Can please explain this: MAX(CASE WHEN leave_id = 1 THEN leave_count END)? Is it like IF-ELSE statement? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are not selecting the leave_user_id from the table inside nested select. Hope this will help